# How to make divs which are created when a form is submitted, remain in place when the form is resubmitted

Tags: javascript, php, html, session-cookies

I am making a webpage where the user can use a form to search for a string and then divs will appear showing rows with matching info from a database. Then when a checkbox is clicked on a row it will move up to another div. I would like for the rows which have been selected via the checkbox to remain where they are when the form is resubmitted but still disappear when the checkbox is unclicked.
I have taken this video to show how it is currently working, which should hopefully make my question make sense.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTiQV.jpg

This is the code for my form

```
<form action = "" method = "POST">
    <div class = "searchcontainer">
        <input id = "search" type="search" name = "search" class = "textbox" placeholder 
        = "Type the students name and press Enter to search...">
        <input type = "submit" style="display:none" id = "submitsearch"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Then when the form is submitted this code will run to create the divs that appear (This is just a really short version, let me know if you need to see all of it)

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['search'])){
        $input = $_POST['search'];
        $result = $conn->query("select * from logins");
        let r<?php echo $studentid ?> = document.createElement("div");
        r<?php echo $studentid ?>.id = "r<?php echo $studentid ?>";
        r<?php echo $studentid ?>.className = "rowcontainer";
        document.getElementById("tablecontainer").appendChild(r<?php echo $studentid ? 
        >);
```

Then this is the Javascript code which moves the rows to the 'selected' container when the checkbox is ticked and back to  the 'tablecontainer' when unckecked.

```
<script>
    const main = document.querySelector(".tablecontainer");
    const selected = document.querySelector(".selected");
    main.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        const tgt = e.target;
        if (tgt.classList.contains("move")) {
            const rowContainer = tgt.closest(".rowcontainer");
            if (tgt.checked) {
                selected.append(rowContainer);
            }
        }
    })
    selected.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    const tgt = e.target;
    if (tgt.classList.contains("move")) {
        const rowContainer = tgt.closest(".rowcontainer");
        main.append(rowContainer)
        }
    })
</script>
```

From what I found online it looks like I will need to se session variables to keep the rows in place once they have been selected, but I dont really know how to do this, so help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Edit: I have a had a look through these answers but as a beginner they do not make much sense to me. I have found that I can use

```
var rowsselected = document.getElementById("selected").children;
```

to get a list of all the children divs in my selected div, so is there a way I can save this list so it persists when the form is resubmitted and take the children from this list and append them to selected again. If you could show examples that would be good. Also I should have mentioned this in the main post but I would also like to carry over info from the rows which have been selected to the next page so if I could make the ids of these rows into session variables or something like that that would be good.

Comment: When you submit form by default current page gets refreshed. Which means it sends data to current page only. That time your `if(isset($_POST['search'])){` gets satisfied. So in short upon page refresh your state is lost. so you are unable to keep track of which item where click which not. I would suggest fire event on button click, get data using ajax requst and bind data to div. Upon click on particular item save its value in any global array. and when you make new ajax request just append your response with gloobal array and generate dynamic html and append to any result div.

Comment: Or you can save your selected items in localStorage, So they do not get lost even when the form is submitted or resubmitted.

Comment: Use AJAX to get the search result instead of form submit. Then use submit to send the selected items to server.